# Can not connect to CoAP Resource on Arduino

Tags: arduino, coap

I'm trying to set up a basic IoT Project. I managed to get a Coap Server Running on the Arduino UNO with Ethernet shield using the microcoap library (https://github.com/1248/microcoap) .
It works trying to get the Resource via the Firefox Copper Plugin.

Now im trying to use the californium library (http://people.inf.ethz.ch/mkovatsc/californium.php) to get the resource and use it in my java programm. But it is getting no response. If i make a CoaP Server using Califorium i can acess that resource without problem.

For the microcoap library it says:
"Arduino, by default, has a UDP transmit buffer of 24 bytes. This is too small for some endpoints and will result in an error."

Could that be the reason it is not working? Is there any difference trying to access a resource with copper and californium. If so what properties could i try to change to make it work?